# Java return an implementation of a builder

Tags: java, generics, builder

I made a functional builder for a class which works like so

```java
new ComponentStatus.Builder()
        .with($ -> {
          $.name = element.getName();
          $.state = element.getState();
          $.status = element.getStatus();
          $.description = element.getStatusDescription();
        }).build();
```

The class is

```java
public class ComponentStatus {

  private final String name;
  private final int state;
  private final int status;
  private final String description;

  ComponentStatus(String name, int state, int status, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
    this.status = status;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public static class Builder {

    public String name;
    public int state;
    public int status;
    public String description;

    Builder with(
        Consumer<Builder> builderFunction) {
      builderFunction.accept(this);
      return this;
    }

    ComponentStatus build() {
      return new ComponentStatus(name, state, status, description);
    }

  }
}
```

It works. Now I want to add a builder to other classes.
The `with()` method will always be the same, so I try to make an interface to save on boilerplate

```java
public interface Buildable {

  default Buildable with(
      Consumer<Buildable> builderFunction) {
    builderFunction.accept(this);
    return this;
  }

    Object build();
}
```

This doesn't work since `with()` returns `Buildable` and not `<? extends Buildable>` but changing the return type doesn't work either. What to do?

Comment: Do you realize that this `with` method does not simplify anything? Compare with `ComponentStatus  result; { var b = new ComponentStatus.Builder(); b.name = element.getName(); b.state = element.getState(); b.status = element.getStatus(); b.description = element.getStatusDescription(); result = b.build(); }`

Comment: @Holger ok, but its fluent

Comment: But once you took the time to write a builder, why not provide it with dedicated methods, so the code using it can look like `ComponentStatus result = ComponentStatus.builder() .name(element.getName()) .state(element.getState()) .status(element.getStatus()) .description(element.getStatusDescription()) .build();` Why do you focus on the code size of the builder rather than the code using it?

Comment: @Holger I suppose I could add withName() etc. https://medium.com/beingprofessional/think-functional-advanced-builder-pattern-using-lambda-284714b85ed5 Simple usage is higher priority. I'm exploring my options